# update existing column with results of select query using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-update

I am trying to update a column called `Number_Of_Marks` in our `Results` table using the results we get from our `SELECT` statement. Our select statement is used to count the numbers of marks per module in our results table. The `SELECT` statement works and the output is correct, which is

```
 ResultID   ModuleID   cnt
 -------------------------
   111      ART3452    2                                                          
   114      ART3452    2                                                         
   115      CSC3039    3                                                        
   112      CSC3039    3                                                        
   113      CSC3039    3
```

The table in use is:

Results: `ResultID, ModuleID, Number_Of_Marks`

We need the results of cnt to be updated into our Number_Of_Marks column. This is our code below...

```
DECLARE @cnt INT

SELECT @cnt

SELECT C.cnt
  FROM Results S
       INNER JOIN (SELECT ModuleID, count(ModuleID) as cnt
                     FROM Results 
                    GROUP BY ModuleID) C ON S.ModuleID = C.ModuleID

    UPDATE Results 
    SET [Number_Of_Marks] = (@cnt)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in SQL Server using the `update`/`join` syntax:

```
UPDATE s
  SET [Number_Of_Marks] = c.cnt
  FROM Results S INNER JOIN
       (SELECT ModuleID, count(ModuleID) as cnt
        FROM Results 
        GROUP BY ModuleID
       ) C
       ON S.ModuleID = C.ModuleID;
```

I assume that you want the count from the subquery, not from the uninitialized variable.

EDIT:

In general, when you change the question it is better to ask another question.  Sometimes, though, the changes are really small.  The revised query looks something like:

```
UPDATE s
  SET [Number_Of_Marks] = c.cnt,
      Marks = avgmarks
  FROM Results S INNER JOIN
       (SELECT ModuleID, count(ModuleID) as cnt, avg(marks * 1.0) as avgmarks
        FROM Results 
        GROUP BY ModuleID
       ) C
       ON S.ModuleID = C.ModuleID;
```

Note that I multiplied the `marks` by `1.0`.  This is a quick-and-dirty way to convert an integer to a numeric value.  SQL Server takes averages on integers and produces an integer.  Usually you want some sort of decimal or floating value.